# _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault returned a result with an error set during fit Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm actually trying to train a Keras Model. I can compile it but when I try to fit it I get this result :

"SystemError: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault returned a result with an error set"

I never had such an error, can you help please ?

Thanks a lot !

Here the Model :

```
input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_size,1))

h_t_1 = tf.constant(0,shape=(1,input_size,1),dtype = 'float32')

encoded = layers.Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(input_size, 1))(input_img)
encoded = layers.Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=3)(encoded)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling1D(128)(encoded)
encoded = layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences= False)(encoded)

h_t = layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True)(h_t_1)

decoder_input = traitement_input(h_t,encoded)

decoded = layers.LSTM(128)(decoder_input)
decoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

h_t_1 = tf.identity(decoded)


autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

And the complete error :

```py
StagingError: in user code:

    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:799 train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:528 minimize
        grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:580 _compute_gradients
        grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:473 _get_gradients
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py:1074 gradient
        flat_grad = imperative_grad.imperative_grad(
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py:71 imperative_grad
        return pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(
    C:\Users\s611961\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py:844 _backward_function
        call_op = outputs[0].op

    SystemError: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: Please always include the full traceback, not individual parts of the errors, as they make no sense in isolation.

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue, so can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!